# Parenting Mesh with Bone

Tags: cycles-render-engine, bones, parent, motion-capture

So I was watching this tutorial on how to make a lightsaber (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxMI4aT4FQQ), and at time 16:12, he asks to parent the bone and the mesh, like he says, I hold shift and then I select the mesh, then the bone, and then press ctrl+p to parent, I then press parent with envelope weights, like he said... I do that, then i play it,and then only the bottom is moving and pivoting and following with the motion tracking... Could someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Select "bone" instead of parenting it with "envelope weights"